# Proper way to get an array of values from Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently coding a newsletter system. In order to send the mail, I need to get all e-mail addresses from my database (of course).

So I created a custom repository method, as follows :

```
public function getEmailAddresses()
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u.email')
        ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u')
        ->where('u.isNewsletterSubscriber = true')
    ;

    $results =  $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    $addresses = [];
    foreach($results as $line) {
        $addresses[] = $line['email'];
    }

    return $addresses;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do so than treating the result to get a "plain" array containing only e-mail addresses. In effect, after `$query->getQuery()->getResult()`, I get something like this :

```
'results' =>
 [0] => array('email' => 'first@email.com')
 [1] => array('email' => 'second@email.com')
```

And as I said, I want something like this :

```
array('first@email.com', 'second@email.com')
```

Does a cleaner way to do that exist using Doctrine2 built-in methods ? I've tried with different hydratation modes but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably [create a custom hydrator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes), but there's really no issue with just doing it the way you are right now.  You could also do it in the following ways:

### PHP <= 5.4

```
return array_map('current', $addresses);
```

### PHP >= 5.5

```
return array_column($addresses, 'email');
```

The `array_column` function was introduced in PHP 5.5.0 and does what you're looking for.  The `array_map` function will work otherwise, calling PHP's internal `current` function which simply returns the value of the current element (which is always initialized to the first element of that array).

Be careful with using `array_map` if you have a large number of rows returned, because it will likely be slower and it will definitely take up a lot more memory since it has to copy the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can run pure sql with doctrine (DBAL):

example:

```
public function getEmails()
{
    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT u.email FROM user AS u');

    $connection->execute();

    return $connection->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
```

Comment: Oops accidentally deleted my comment, but I was incorrect and you were right - it is using the DBAL layer of Doctrine which runs pure SQL queries.  The only difference is you cannot use the reference to the object names that the ORM uses (like `AppBundle:User`) and you instead have to use the database table and column names.

Comment: @JasonRoman haha, I already edited my answer:), thanks for the useful information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try other $hydrationModes, maybe that help

getResult( mixed $hydrationMode = Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT )

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the `getArrayResult` method, so doctrine must not hydrate each object (this is the expensive task from doctrine).

```
public function getEmailAddresses()
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT u.email FROM AppBundle:User u WHERE u.isNewsletterSubscriber = true');

    return array_map('current', $q->getArrayResult());
}
```